How does Signal Protocol's X3DH's Deniability work?
In Signal Protocol's X3DH implementation:
https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/
it says:

4.4. Deniability: X3DH doesn't give either Alice or Bob a publishable cryptographic proof of the contents of their communication or the fact that they communicated.

I am failing to understand how this is true. Previously it says:

Alice then sends Bob an initial message containing:
Alice's identity key IKA
Alice's ephemeral key EKA
Identifiers stating which of Bob's prekeys Alice used

And it says:

Upon receiving Alice's initial message, Bob retrieves Alice's identity key and ephemeral key from the message. Bob also loads his identity private key, and the private key(s) corresponding to whichever signed prekey and one-time prekey (if any) Alice used.

Aren't Alice's identity key IKA and Identifiers stating which of Bob's prekeys Alice used sufficient cryptographic proof that they communicated?

The guarantee of deniability is that a transcript of a signal communication isn't convincing evidence that a party, such as Alice, actually voluntarily participated in a conversation. Bob might want to try implicating Alice in a conversation that never happened. So, as a judge, you can't just see some traffic that shows IK_A and say, yep, Alice sent this message.
Why is this the case in signal? Signal's handshake is essentially a bunch of Diffie-Hellman exchanges. Consider a single one of these shared DH secret $G^{xy}$. Crucially, Bob has the other end of the shared secret, so Bob is fully capable of fabricating a valid transcript that an external judge will accept.
Key exchanges with these capabilities are so-called (offline) deniable key exchanges. The offline qualifier is important and captures the fact that the judge only receives a transcript after the fact. Online deniability seems difficult (impossible?). See "On the Cryptographic Deniability of the Signal
Protocol" for more details on the deniability of Signal.
